# Canny Edge detector threshold values gives different result

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

I am trying to find contour of a  image, before that I am applying Canny's edge detector.
It's giving different result for different images.For one image it's giving perfect contours at threshold value - min-40 max-240 and for other image its 30-120.
I want to make it generic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In laymen terms, edge detection needs a threshold to tell what difference/change should be counted as edge. For details read [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html).

So, the edges depend on the the content of image ie the level of brightness/darkness/contrast.
I suggest you to simply find the mean of whole gray image and take threshold as follows:

min_threshold = 0.66 * mean

max_threshold = 1.33 * mean

I have tested it and it gives impressive result. You can use median instead of mean, with almost same result. Another alternative is to first equalize the image and then try threshold of your choice/experimental.

But again again strongly recommend to try mean method. In case of any query, write here.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: hi parvez thanks for the reply..for good quality images its working perfect..ur way is now covering 60% of cases :).
Can u suggest me any alternative for the contour detection??

Comment: Hi, I'm glad it helped. Please give some samples of problematic image to focus on problem.

Comment: Hello! I will give a try to your way of setting the threshold...Are you talking about the mean of the gray levels on the input image? or the mean of the gradient image? Where does the values 0.66 and 1.33 comes from?

Comment: Hi remi, I am talking about raw gray value and  not about gradients. Just give it a try.. I visualized it when I was working on a similar stuff.

Comment: Hi parvez..here is link of image I was working on
http://i.imgur.com/mq9YBH7.jpg?1
its not giving me enough contours with your values...but when i used high resolution camera with 5mega pixel camera or more ..its giving me good results(70-80%)..thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Rahul, the image you attached is not normal/natural scene content. Human can recognise it as binary image. So I suggest you to try the very next thing I suggested in my answer ie instead using mean, try finding approx median of gray image and keep everything same. Please post your result if further discussion required.

Comment: Hi parvez..i tried using median too but values are nearly same and the image is too poor to find the edge..so should i put some restriction on input like with flash(or good  brightness) to get the output?

Comment: Flash/brightness is not right measure. Better the contrast, better the edges. Look, As the image is actually binary and human understand it, I would suggest you to apply some gray value threshold or just try adaptiveThreshold of opencv, the output will be edge in your case. One more thing, is you can scale down image at various factors and see which factor is giving you best edge. For the attached image, scaling by half gives canny and adaptive threshold the best edge. Hope this help.