# Compare two videos using Image processing

Tags: c++, image-processing, edge-detection

Hi i am new to image processing.I want to compare two videos using image processing.First type of video has effect(blur) in video.And second type is normal video. Using edge detection i want to compare two videos.So i want to use canny edge detection.Is there any guide to help to do this project.I want to extract some information in edge video.i thought using canny edge detection identify edge and extract information from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adi has given good point, apart from that I would suggest you to see [Canny Edge detector threshold values gives different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862374/canny-edge-detector-threshold-values-gives-different-result/24863709#24863709) for better edge detection without bothering small differences in lighting and contrast, otherwise your result may differ.

For matching edges, see ECR.

Apart from that I would suggest you to add multiple methods for video matching to avoid high processing and false-positive. e.g. if you compare histogram(it is quite simple easy and fast) and if difference is very high, no need to compare edges(comparatively process intensive).

Comment: Thanks for your help.if i using canny edge detection how to compare edge detection values in two videos.It means how to extract numeric features from canny edge detection

Comment: For matching edge, I already suggested ECR: Edge change ratio, it is quite good. Second, if you want to apply ECR to match images then it is great. Otherwise for videos, we have to see what are constraints.. like difference in time, in which case you need match something like longest common sub-sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Edge detection is generally not invariant to blurring.

If you still want to use edge detection, then you might blur your *un-blurred* video, and then do the comparison. If the blur is strong, you should consider sub-sampling the frames (e.g. keep every 2nd row/col pixel) and do the edge-detection and comparison on the reduce frames. This will be faster and also give the edge-detection stronger edge to detect.

Comment: Thanks for your help.if i using canny edge detection how to compare edge detection values in two videos.It means how to extract numeric features from canny edge detection.

Comment: This discussion is pretty hypothetical, since I don't think Canny is the right thing to do. In any case, you might try a simple binary XOR and count the number of overlapping pixels.

Comment: is there any way to use edge detection to compare two videos ??

Comment: That's what I suggested.