# opencv canny: Do minVal and maxVal matter if you're working with a black and white image?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, edge-detection, canny-operator

Preface: This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24863709/109941).

Consider the following code, taken from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html#gsc.tab=0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200) # Would 100 and 200 matter if your original image was black and white?

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

My Question:

- When using open cv's canny function, do your choices for minVal and maxVal matter if you're working with a black and white image?

Reason I ask:

- I've experimented with many values and they don't seem to matter.

Comment: see Miki's answer. But just as a thought: Probably there are better (more efficient) edge detection techniques for bw images than canny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The threshold values **do** matter.

---

Assuming a `3x3` Sobel filter (as in `Canny`), the possible values for `dx` and `dy` you can get for an input binary `(0, 255)` image are:

```
-1020, -765, -510, -255, 0, 255, 510, 765, 1020
```

And the possible magnitude values are:

1. **L1** (default) : `0, 510, 1020, 1530`.
2. **L2** : `0, 360.63, 510, 721.25, 806.38, 1020, 1081.87, 1140.40`

So, you'll get different output images from Canny if you use, for example `(minVal, maxVal)` as `(200,400)` or `(400,600)`.

If you use thresholds that are in the same interval (the boundary of the intervals are the magnitude values shown above), then you'll get always the same result.

Comment: note: sobel kernel looks like [[-1,-2,-1], [0,0,0], [+1,+2,+1]]. so the extreme case would be a hard gradient aligned with the kernel, 4*255 - 4*0 = 1020 (and equivalent others). that explains the first set of numbers. both x and y kernels can't both be maxed out at the same time (no such-valued 3x3 patch is possible), so the L1 norm must be less than 2*1020. I don't care to derive the 1530 number but it's probably right.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I don't remember how I computed these values 6 years ago... Also nobody double checked them, so there's the possibility that there is some mistake :)

Comment: all values check out. evaluating all 2^9=512 possible images under those kernels goes quickly. it's a handful of lines in python. useful was `np.binary_repr(num, width=9)`, turns number into bit array