# Canny algorithm from openCV: What does the Threshold values really mean and why can they be higher than the values of the array?

Tags: python, opencv, threshold, canny-operator

I am trying to perform the Canny edge detection algorithm of OpenCV to an image array, whose values range from 0 to 255.

I am struggling to understand the role of the thresholds in the cv2.canny() function because for example, when I use threshold values of (MinThr=300, MaxThr=400) or (MinThr=350, MaxThr=450) I get different results. I don't understand why this happen since I thought that the Thresholds values that I define, couldn't be higher than the maximum value of the pixels in the array (in my case 255).

The other answers that I saw at Stackoverflow didn't help, so if someone could enlight me I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opencv canny: Do minVal and maxVal matter if you're working with a black and white image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102372/opencv-canny-do-minval-and-maxval-matter-if-youre-working-with-a-black-and-whi)

Answer (score 1):

The thresholds are applied not to the original image intensity, but to its gradient magnitude, which maximal value is about 4 times larger than the maximal image intensity, because it is estimated using the [Sobel](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html) operator. So you will stop seeing the difference (actually you will get an empty result) when the upper threshold exceeds 1000 and something. For details see [Canny tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html).

Comment: even more than 4 times. see existing question+answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102372/opencv-canny-do-minval-and-maxval-matter-if-youre-working-with-a-black-and-whi

Comment: To be precise, the maximal theoretical Sobel gradient magnitude is 6 times the maximal intensity. It is achieved on `[[255, 255, ?], [255, ?, 0], [?, 0, 0]]` and `[[0, 0, ?], [0, ?, 255], [?, 255, 255]]` (values at positions marked `?` don't matter). No need to test all possible combinations, simple reasoning is sufficient :) But on real images such values are extremely rare unless you deal with some binary drawing. But in this case Canny is most probably an overkill.